# Finding expected value of Bernoulli random variables

Tags: statistics, random-variables, bernoulli-numbers

Consider a sequence of $n$ Bernoulli trials with $P(\text{success})=p$. Let $X_i$ and $X_j$ be indicator variables of the number of "success" in $i$th and $j$th runs with $i<j$. In other words $X_i=1$ if the $ith$ trial is success and $0$ otherwise.. Given the total number of success was $m$. I am asked to compute the correlation coefficient for $X_i$ and $X_j$.

To compute the co-variance I will need to find $E(X_i)$ and $E(X_j)$ first. By definition $E(X_i)=p$ =$E(X_j)$. But how should I find E($X^2_i$)?

Comment: "Total number of successes" in what?

Comment: m is the total number of observed successes in n trials. 0 < m < n.

Comment: This reproduces the misleading formulations of a recent previous duplicate question by the OP, although a correct statement of the question was suggested there.

Comment: ...Leading to the same tragicomedy of offtopic answers accumulating and the OP choosing to accept one of them with no rationale whatsoever. Now to the third installment?

Comment: The OP now changed silently the answer they accepted. The newly accepted answer at least addresses the question (but with subpar notations). No guarantee this means the OP's understanding is any better though, I am afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have observed $m$ successes in $n$ trials, $p$ is irrelevant.  Let $X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n,p)$ be the total number of successes in $n$ trials.  The idea is to think of all possible sequences from $[0,1]^n$ such that exactly $m$ of the entries are $1$, and we have for any $i < j$, $$\operatorname{E}[X_i X_j \mid X = m] = \Pr[X_i = X_j = 1 \mid X = m] = \frac{\binom{2}{2} \binom{n-2}{m-2}}{\binom{n}{m}} = \frac{m(m-1)}{n(n-1)}.$$  Similarly, $$\operatorname{E}[X_i \mid X = m] = \Pr[X_i = 1 \mid X = m] = \frac{\binom{1}{1} \binom{n-1}{m-1}}{\binom{n}{m}} = \frac{m}{n}.$$  It follows that $$\operatorname{Cov}[X_i, X_j \mid X = m] = \frac{m(m-1)}{n(n-1)} - \frac{m^2}{n^2}$$ and the correlation is $$(\rho_{ij} \mid X = m) = \frac{1}{1-n}.$$  Note this result is independent of $m$, and note the relationship of the conditional expectations to the hypergeometric distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Let the pdf of $X$ be $f_{X}(x)$. Then, $E[g(x)] = \sum_{x}g(x)f_{X}(x)$. Thus,

$E(X_{i}^{2}) = \sum_{x=0}^{1}x^{2} * \Pr(X_{i} = x) = 0^{2}*(1-p) + 1^{2}*p = p$

Comment: Thank you! I came up the same answer. Using the same method, would E($X_i$$X_j$)=p as well?

Comment: @user396433 Since the trials are Bernoulli trials, Thus $X_{i}$ and $X_{j}$ are independent and we have, $E(X_{i}X_{j}) = E(X_{i})E(X_{j}) = p*p = p^{2}$

Comment: @user396433 Seriously, how does this address your question? Do you even understand the words you use?